# PhoneGap - Approach to authenticate against a remote website?

Tags: iphone, ajax, asynchronous, cordova

I'm playing with PhoneGap for the first time.  I'd like to do the following:

Create a login UI in the file index.html like so:

```
<input id="email">
<input id="password">
<button id="login">Login</button>
```

The UI will appear on an iphone.  When user clicks the login button, I want to asychronously authenticate against the website http://mysite.com/login.  If authentication fails, user stays on the index.html UI.  If authentication succeeds, user sees a new UI found in dashboard.html, which looks like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>task 1</li>
   <li>task 2</li>
   <li>task 3 etc... (asychronously retrieve data from http://mysite.com)</li>
</ul>
```

The user can perform asynchronous actions against the list in dashboard.html.  So to do this, the server-side scripts must always check to see if user has the appropriate permissions.

SO my questions are:

**1) I've outlined what I'd like to achieve, but i've also suggested web-development philsophy to solving the problem.   Is there a better overall approach?**

2) Which asynchronous technology should I use? Ajax, webservice, something else?

3) Can I still use SESSION on the server side to maintain user session data like user_id, roles, permissions etc...  That way the client machine doesn't have to transmit this data with every asynchronous call?

Comment: A related question on how to AJAX user authenticate with PhoneGap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709315/phonegap-cookie-based-authentication-php-not-working-webview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. good approach
2. I would suggest ajax with json response
3. Yes you can still use session variables

remember in the end, that the phonegap application is really just a web page running in a container created by phonegap.

Here is a [phonegap plugin I wrote](http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/1012434483/phonegap-and-iphone-development) for logging into a system running SSL

Excellent [PhoneGap Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/) is here and don't forget the [PhoneGap Wiki](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494772/FrontPage) has great stuff too

Comment: no, plugins are platform specific, I will create an android version since it is a secondary platform for me

Comment: @AaronSaunders Nice plugin. Please update when you create Android version of the plugin. I'm waiting for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.preventDefault on submit button in case of no authentication..
Ajax and json is the solution.. But careful about the cross-domain policy if you debug on browser...best debug on emulator.