# Manually set Cookie header with PhoneGap FileTransfer

Tags: session, cordova, cookies, file-transfer

I have an issue with Cookies, when setting them manually for a Phonegap FileTransfer request.

I tried to set the cookie using

```
   document.cookie="JSESSIONID=........";
```

and

```
   params.headers={'Cookie':"JSESSIONID=..."};
```

Then making these changes that I found someone suggesting:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3709746/249328

But after all this, no Cookie header is sent in the request.

I need to set this cookie manually because I am using FileTransfer for a request.

Any help or suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added ;jsessionid=.... at the end of my URL, and this worked for me

Comment: I also added a phonegap plugin, to force resetting cookies before the request

Comment: Please provide this as an answer to the question.