# Maintaining django session in phonegap application

Tags: python, django, session, cordova

I am having difficulties with maintaining a session in django. Basically I can't login to my web application. I want to create a phonegap app which would communicate with the server using ajax requests but it has to login and set up a session to be able to do that. Django uses cookies session_id for that and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this behavior in Android, but maybe this is happening in iOS? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3709746/1345237.